# Shadow in Matlab GUI Window

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have implemented a GUI in Matlab.
The GUI window shows a shadow (outside) to highlight from other windows in the screen. 
When I print or capture this window it also save the shadow of the frame.
I would like to remove the shadow of the GUI window.

Could somebody help me to solve it?

Regards

Comment: Try [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig) which will only export the highlight part.

Comment: After trying different options I found 'capture window' program, e.g.as PNG, the easiest way.